# How to remove the "Sign in" control from Visual Studio 2019 title bar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I couldn't find a relevant checkbox or setting in the Tools > Options or Tools > Customize, and the VSIX extensions I could find are too radical and remove the entire title bar, which is not what I want. The quick search toolbar also doesn't help. I just want to remove the "Sign in" button as I don't use an account and it eats up valuable space in my already cramped main toolbar and the project name gets ellipsized in the middle.

[image: screenshot of the title bar with the "Sign in" button marked with a blue rectangle]

Comment: In older versions of VS the [nofun](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ihameed.nofun) extension could do this. Maybe this will be ported in 2019?

Comment: @Richard I'm not familiar with F# but I suppose it could be recompiled if we change the metadata to say it supports msvs2019? Last commit to that repo was 2 years ago, so only if someone experienced can fork this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the “Sign in” control from Visual Studio 2019 title bar installing my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and importing [Hide Sign in (VS 2019)](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/code/Hide%20Sign%20in%20(VS%202019).vcmd) extension.

Comment: This is not working in MSVS 2022 anymore. "Sign In" crap reappears after a few seconds upon visual studio load.

Comment: @Mooh Please edit the extension code and change "16" to "17" on the first line to enable it in VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so this is not truly meant as an answer (unless it IS...), but have you looked around in this Customize area yet:
[image]

Also, my menu is not set up as you describe: Tools > Options or Tools > Customize. 
Mine is Tools > Customize, or Tools > Options.

Comment: I imagine MS wants people to have to sign in.

Comment: Yes, as I described, I have, but I couldn't find it. Maybe it has a weird unintuitive name and I looked it over. If it's there and someone knows what it's called, please comment.